# why my code calling API for multiple time instedof just once after delaying of 500 ms using debounce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debouncing

I'm trying to call API using debounce but in this case, API calling for every character,
for example, I type hello in search then it calls for he, hel, hell, and hello but I want only for final word hello

```
  useEffect(() => {
    updateDebounceWord(word);
  }, [word]);

  const updateDebounceWord = debounce(() => {
    {
      word.length > 1 && dictionaryApi();
    }
  });

  function debounce(cb, delay = 500) {
    let timer = null;
    return (...args) => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        cb(...args);
      }, delay);
    };
  }

const dictionaryApi = async () => {
    // inital state []
    console.log("hited")
    try {
      const data = await axios.get(
        `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/${category}/${word}`
      );
      console.log("Fetched",word);
      setMeanings(data.data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error||", e);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Dilshans explanation, I wan't to suggest making a hook out of your debounce function, so you can easily reuse it:

```js
const useDebounce = (cb, delay = 500) => {
  const timer = useRef();

  // this cleans up any remaining timeout when the hooks lifecycle ends
  useEffect(() => () => clearTimeout(timer.current), [cb, delay]);

  return useCallback(
    (...args) => {
      clearTimeout(timer.current);
      timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
        cb(...args);
      }, delay);
    },
    [cb, delay]
  );
};
```

use it like this in your components:

```js
const updateDebounceWord = useDebounce((word) => {
  console.log("api call here", word);
});

useEffect(() => {
  updateDebounceWord(word);
}, [word, updateDebounceWord]);
```

Comment: Yep. I forgot about `useRef` :) This should be the correct way & create a custom hook just like this.

Comment: I don't know react that well, wouldn't something like `const updateDebounceWord 
 = React.useCallback(debounce(() => {{word.length > 1 && dictionaryApi();}}))` already do the trick?

Comment: But I guess that part `//this cleans up any remaining timeout when the hooks lifecycle ends` makes the cleanup much easier, without risking any side effects on unmount.

Comment: Generally, this would work as well. But in this case, you have to define the debounce function somewhere. Since it needs to hold some state (the timer), a hook is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Yes I was just wondering regarding of reusability of a `debounce` function which can be quite common for larger projects.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `debounce` on render phase of the component. so each time when the component rebuild a new tree due to the state update, the `updateDebounceWord` will redeclare. Both `current` and `workInProgress` node of the component will not share any data. If you want to share the data between `current` and `workInProgress` tree use `useRef` or else put in global scope

A quick fix is, put the `timer` variable in global scope.

```
// keep this on global scope
let timer = null;

function debounce(cb, delay = 500) {

  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      cb(...args);
    }, delay);
  };
}

export default function App() {
  const [word, setWord] = useState("");

  const sendReq = debounce((keyword) => {
    apiReq(keyword);
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (word.length > 0) {
      sendReq(word);
    }
  }, [word, sendReq])


  const apiReq = (keyword) => {
    console.log('reached', keyword);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={word} onChange={(e) => setWord(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Also put all the dependencies in the `useEffect` dep array otherwise it may not work as expected.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    updateDebounceWord(word);
  }, [word, updateDebounceWord]);
```

Comment: @t.niese It might correct in normal javaScript. In react the OP using the debounce in render phase which means each time the React will re declare `updateDebounceWord`. By stack I'm talking about the virtual stack of the FiberNode of this component.

Comment: @t.niese there are ways to make it work in React. Like the Fitzi suggested in his answer by using `useRef`. Creating a custom hook as he did but the OP's problem was debouncing is not work as expected. The reason behind that is because, react will call the `App()` function each and every time when a state change trigger. Flushing the new tree to the host tree is decided by reconciliation algorithm but since React call `App()` each time, two instances return two separate objects.

Comment: after first mount somewhere in React => `const appInCurrentTree = App();`. Then user type a key `h`, then React will go through the tree again and create `const appInWorkTree = App();`.  So how'd you expect to clear the timeout in `appInCurrentTree` from `appInWorkTree` ? The only way to do that is keep it in a shared memory

Comment: Yes it is bad to put in global. Bad for testing as well. Best place is the useRef

Comment: @t.niese updated that part..

Comment: I would also note the downsides of the global approach. I'll clean up the discussion here under the thread. And remove my comments.