# why this onChange method has invoked several times(infinity) and how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

actually, I am new to React and I am trying to put debouncing along with the event method(onChange) in input to make the code optimized, but when the event occurs instead of calling the function for one time it calls several times(up to infinity).

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

  var input_ref = useRef(null)
  
//.............Debouncing........................................................

  var debouncing = (callback,threshold)=>{
    var timer;
    return function(){
        const context = this

        if(timer)clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setInterval(()=>{
            timer = null;
            callback.apply(context);
            //callback()
        },threshold);
    }
}

//........EventHandler with Debouncing............................................

var search_data = debouncing(()=>{
    console.log(input_ref.current.value)
},300)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" name='searchBox' placeholder="search" ref={input_ref} onChange={search_data}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

link (CodeSandbox):- https://codesandbox.io/s/debouncing-testing-gxc031?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72675774/11306028) your question

Answer (score 0):

Haha dude, your code works fine except a little bit carelessness: it should be `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` at [line 14](https://codesandbox.io/s/debouncing-testing-gxc031?file=/src/App.js:270-304) :P

Comment: ohh ur right :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, you use setInterval instead of setTimeout.
Second, the debounce function doesn't work fine, I just rewrote it for you, Also it would be better to move it outside the component function, please check the code below it's working as required.

https://codesandbox.io/s/debouncing-testing-forked-ig9vbf

Comment: can u please explain the reason, why we should move the debounce func. outside the component function, because in both cases(inside and outside) it worked but as u mentioned to take it outside of the component.

Comment: Yes, it will work in both cases, but whenever react component re-render it will re-initialize the debounce function, and as it doesn't have an effect in the component state, it's best practice to move it outside.